# Why is client side tcp sometimes not sending ACKs, leading to retransmits?

Tags: tcp, packet

Here's what I have:

Client side (192.168.11.121):Windows Vista,Firefox

Server side (192.168.11.16): Windows 2003, My web server or IIS

Fiddler running on the client shows that some images take much longer to download than others, even though images are same size.  I ran a client side packet trace and found that the difference between the "fast" and "slow" downloads is that for the slow downloads, the client is receiving the data quickly but not sending ACKs, leading the server to retransmit.  The first trace below contains both a successful and a slow request.

A successful image request:
1132 is the image request from the browser
1133-1155 is the response.  As the server sends data packets, the client ACKs them as they arrive

An image request with retransmits:
1159 is the image request from the browser
1160-1182 is the response.  This time the client is not ACKing the packets.
1183 is a duplicate ack from the client to server - why?

I have read about delayed ACKs but I don't think the conditions apply, as the client should be acking at least every other packet, right?

Does client think there is a missing packet and is therefore not sending the acks?  Is there a missing packet?  If so, I don't see it.

I have tried 2 client machines with this server - problem manifests for both.  Both these clients can download images fine from other servers running same OS and webserver.  So I think it's a server side problem, but what?

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
   1132 7.217259    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [PSH, ACK] Seq=6097 Ack=75896 Win=65700 Len=1016
   1133 7.219314    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=75896 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1134 7.219318    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=77356 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1135 7.219339    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=78816 Win=65700 Len=0
   1136 7.219654    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=78816 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1137 7.219656    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=80276 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1138 7.219659    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=81736 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1139 7.219675    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=83196 Win=65700 Len=0
   1140 7.219978    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=83196 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1141 7.219980    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=84656 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1142 7.219991    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=86116 Win=65700 Len=0
   1143 7.220310    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=86116 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1144 7.220313    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=87576 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1145 7.220315    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=89036 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1146 7.220327    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=90496 Win=65700 Len=0
   1147 7.220645    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=90496 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1148 7.220647    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=91956 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1149 7.220649    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=93416 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1150 7.220662    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=94876 Win=65700 Len=0
   1151 7.220976    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=94876 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1152 7.220978    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=96336 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1153 7.220989    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=97796 Win=65700 Len=0
   1154 7.221316    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=97796 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1155 7.221319    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [PSH, ACK] Seq=99256 Ack=7113 Win=64519 Len=710
   1156 7.221335    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=99966 Win=65700 Len=0
   1159 7.414879    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [PSH, ACK] Seq=7113 Ack=99966 Win=65700 Len=1016
   1160 7.417006    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=99966 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1161 7.417009    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=101426 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1162 7.417337    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=102886 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1163 7.417339    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=104346 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1164 7.417343    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=105806 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1165 7.417661    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=107266 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1166 7.417664    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=108726 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1167 7.418004    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=110186 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1168 7.418006    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=111646 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1169 7.418008    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=113106 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1170 7.418336    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=114566 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1171 7.418339    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=116026 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1172 7.418342    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=117486 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1173 7.418674    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=118946 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1174 7.418677    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=120406 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1175 7.419002    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=121866 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1176 7.419004    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=123326 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1177 7.419007    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=124786 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1178 7.419375    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=126246 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1179 7.419378    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=127706 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1180 7.419708    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=129166 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1181 7.419710    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=130626 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1182 7.419712    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [PSH, ACK] Seq=132086 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=316
   1183 7.419741    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 1159#1] 60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=99966 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1186 7.617479    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 1182#1] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=132402 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=0
   1187 7.742696    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=99966 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1188 7.939708    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=101426 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1189 7.940725    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=101426 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1190 7.940727    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=102886 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1191 7.940750    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=104346 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1192 7.941698    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=104346 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1193 7.941700    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=105806 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1194 7.941712    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=107266 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1195 7.942030    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=107266 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1196 7.942684    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=108726 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1197 7.942687    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=110186 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1198 7.942700    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=111646 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1199 7.943015    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=111646 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1200 7.943651    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=113106 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1201 7.943653    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=114566 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1202 7.943664    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=116026 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1203 7.943983    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=116026 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1204 7.943985    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=117486 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1205 7.943995    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=118946 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1206 7.944665    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=118946 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1207 7.944667    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=120406 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1208 7.944681    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=121866 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1209 7.944999    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=121866 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1210 7.945002    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=123326 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1211 7.945004    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=124786 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1212 7.945018    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=126246 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1213 7.945330    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=126246 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1214 7.945333    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=127706 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1215 7.945344    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=129166 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1216 7.945664    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=129166 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1217 7.945667    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=130626 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=1460
   1218 7.945669    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [PSH, ACK] Seq=132086 Ack=8129 Win=65535 Len=316
   1219 7.945686    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=132402 Win=65700 Len=0
   1220 7.945692    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 1219#1] 60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=132402 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=132086 SRE=132402
   1223 8.038426    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [PSH, ACK] Seq=8129 Ack=132402 Win=65700 Len=1016
   1224 8.040480    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=132402 Ack=9145 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1225 8.040482    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=133862 Ack=9145 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1226 8.040499    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=9145 Ack=135322 Win=65700 Len=0
   1227 8.040813    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=135322 Ack=9145 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1228 8.040815    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=136782 Ack=9145 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1229 8.040817    192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      ddi-tcp-1 > 60781 [ACK] Seq=138242 Ack=9145 Win=64519 Len=1460
   1230 8.040830    192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      60781 > ddi-tcp-1 [ACK] Seq=9145 Ack=139702 Win=65700 Len=0
```

I see the same behavior downloading images from IIS on this server:

```
   No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
    287 22.257956   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [PSH, ACK] Seq=4531 Ack=86993 Win=65700 Len=869
    288 22.261529   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=86993 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    289 22.261532   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=88453 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    290 22.261859   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=89913 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    291 22.261861   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=91373 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    292 22.261864   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=92833 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    293 22.262194   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=94293 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    294 22.262196   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=95753 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    295 22.262526   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=97213 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    296 22.262527   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=98673 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    297 22.262530   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=100133 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    298 22.262858   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=101593 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    299 22.262860   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=103053 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    300 22.263193   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=104513 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    301 22.263196   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=105973 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    302 22.263197   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=107433 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    303 22.263530   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=108893 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    304 22.263532   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=110353 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    305 22.263534   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=111813 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    306 22.263863   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=113273 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    307 22.263865   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=114733 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    308 22.264196   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=116193 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    309 22.264198   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=117653 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    310 22.264200   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=119113 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    311 22.264528   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=120573 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    312 22.264531   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=122033 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    313 22.264533   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=123493 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    314 22.264859   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      http > 49387 [PSH, ACK] Seq=124953 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=928
    315 22.264886   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 287#1] 49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=86993 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    324 22.459724   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 314#1] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=125881 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=0
    326 22.788166   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=86993 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    330 22.980324   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=88453 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    331 22.981699   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=88453 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    332 22.981703   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=89913 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    333 22.981755   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=91373 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    334 22.983025   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=91373 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    335 22.983028   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=92833 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    336 22.983034   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=94293 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    337 22.983085   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=95753 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    338 22.984287   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=95753 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    339 22.984290   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=97213 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    340 22.984292   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=98673 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    341 22.984294   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=100133 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    342 22.984339   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=101593 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    343 22.985373   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=101593 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    344 22.985377   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=103053 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    345 22.985382   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=104513 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    346 22.985435   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=105973 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    347 22.985706   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=105973 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    348 22.985710   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=107433 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    349 22.985753   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=108893 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    350 22.986436   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=108893 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    351 22.986438   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=110353 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    352 22.986459   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=111813 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    353 22.987002   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=111813 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    354 22.987005   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=113273 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    355 22.987011   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=114733 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    356 22.987013   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=116193 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    357 22.987064   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=117653 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    358 22.987174   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=117653 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    359 22.987741   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=119113 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    360 22.987744   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=120573 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    361 22.987747   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=122033 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    362 22.987805   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=123493 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    363 22.988171   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [ACK] Seq=123493 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=1460
    364 22.988175   192.168.11.16         192.168.11.121        TCP      [TCP Retransmission] http > 49387 [PSH, ACK] Seq=124953 Ack=5400 Win=65535 Len=928
    365 22.988219   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=125881 Win=65700 Len=0
    366 22.988236   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 365#1] 49387 > http [ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=125881 Win=65700 Len=0 SLE=124953 SRE=125881
    409 25.633275   192.168.11.121        192.168.11.16         TCP      49387 > http [PSH, ACK] Seq=5400 Ack=125881 Win=65700 Len=990
```

Answer (score 1):

You have run monitoring program in server side (192.168.11.16), right?
So you don't directly see what packets the client received.

But packet number 1183 (selective ack from client 192.168.11.121) tells all what we need:

Client acknowledge bytes from the begin to 99966, and 132086-132401.
Client did not receive packets 1160-1181. Packets 1156 and 1182 where received. So the ack 1183 was triggered by packet 1182.

The problem is not in server or client application. 
There are lot of possible reasons, why packets 1160-1181 were lost between hosts.

We can only start quessing:

Both captured problems seem to be wery similar: Only the last (smaller) packet pass without retransmit. So this could be some kind of PMTU and 'don't fragment' problem. Or just a broken NIC or switch.

Comment: Thanks - you've already helped by pointing me to the SLE/SRE fields. This is a client side trace (I did note that, but was easy to miss).  So the question now is, if 1160-1181 showed up in WireShark on the client, how come the client did not ACK them?